# I'm looking for an application to measure words per minutes when typing

Tags: keyboard, mac, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an application to measure words per minute when typing. It's just a general application without training, and of course it won't detect the wrong typed words but it's ok.

Command line application or GUI application  is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try "TypeFU", from the Mac AppStore...